# Using Django (or simple SQL) - is it possible to sort a m2m relationship with a field on the `through` table?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    toys = models.ManyToManyField('toys.Toy', through='dogs.DogToy')


class DogToy(models.Model):
    dog = models.ForeignKey('dogs.Dog')
    toy = models.ForeignKey('toys.Toy')
    sort_order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('dog', 'toy'),
            ('dog', 'sort_order'),
        )
```

Using the above example, I want to order `dog.toys.all()` using the relationship's `sort_order` column, because multiple dogs may have the same toy, so I can't sort by a field on `Toy`. I can't use Pythonic sorting after the query, because my dogs have thousands of toys, and I need to use pagination for performance.

There have been a few duplicate and almost duplicate questions asked on SO that have been answered incorrectly (answers equivalent to just using `dog.toys.order_by('sort_order')`, which of course doesn't work).

Comment: hmmmm, not sure, but something like dog.toys.all().order_by('dogtoy__sort_order') could do the trick...

Comment: @Jingo I think that's the correct way to do it; the accepted answer is going to hit the database once for the initial query, _and then again for **every** `dogtoy.toy`_.  It can be mitigated with a `.select_related('toy')` in the query, but should be converted to something straightforward like your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it through the intermediate table DogToy:

```
dog = Dog.objects.get(...)
ordered_toys = [dogtoy.toy for dogtoy in \
    DogToy.objects.filter(dog=dog).order_by('sort_order')]
```